# find php extension files command query putty

Tags: wordpress, find

I have to find files with `.php` extension ONLY under uploads directory.

This is easy. I simply go do `cd uploads`  and `find . -name '*.php'`. This works for each directory.

Is there any way to find the same under uploads directory under all websites folders.

My websites are in `/var/www/html/webfiles/` and under `webfiles` there are all WordPress websites. So every websites contains `uploads` folder.

How to find `.PHP` extension files at once for all the Websites under `/var/www/html/webfiles/`

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `grep` you can use regular expressions to find files matching a certain pattern.

```
$ find . -print | grep -i uploads\/.*\.php
```

The above will find case insensitive (`-i`) strings with the pattern `uploads/*.php`.

[More examples](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html)

Comment: and how can I delete all those simultaneously?

Comment: $ find . -print | grep -i uploads\/.*\.php  -exec rm -rf {} \;  Will this work?

Comment: Why use `find`? What's wrong with `ls uploads/ | grep .php` in this case? (or `grep -P '\.php$'` if you must)